# How to update the angle of objects

Tags: sprite-kit

I want to update angle an object is pointing so that it is always pointing in the direction of travel.  I assume that I would put the code to do so in the update method

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
```

How do I find all the objects of a certain category in the scene, I guess I can iterate over all the scene objects but is there a more efficient way to do this perhaps by enumerating over certain categories of objects?

Update:

Another option might be to attach an SKAction to each object.  Is it possible to create a custom action that will be able to use the nodes velocity to change the rotation ?  If so can someone provide sample code.  Thanks

Comment: If you want to be most efficient, you could store them in an array so you are only ever iterating ones that you want to adjust facing. But, performance might be negligible. Depends on your game.

Comment: OK, that seems easy enough.  What about creating a custom SKAction and attaching that to each object ?  Is it possible to convert the objects angularVelocity to a direction in such an action? (another question I guess)!

Comment: How many do you have ? SKActions are more overhead.

Comment: There could be around 100 at any point in time

Comment: Sounds like an array would be the easy way to go.

Comment: if you want efficiency,  100 SKActions firing every 1/60th of a second is not it. :)